# Connection to your rendering host failed , Not Found error In Experience Editor

Tags: sitecore-client, jss

I am working on setup a local XP0 Sitecore 10 development env for training, and one of the learning curves is to host the headless MVP site without containers, I had installed all pre-perquisites, also created a new ASP.NET core site, and published the artifices to it and everything works fine, however, when I tried to open the site in Experience editor I got this error.

`Connection to your rendering host failed with a Not Found error. Ensure the POST endpoint at URL http://mvp-rendering/jss-render has been enabled.`

Checking Sitecore Configuration :

`serverSideRenderingEngineEndpointUrl="http://mvp-rendering/jss-render"`

Not sure what is the "/jss-render" that is part of the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Not Found error can be misleading, it's output for any web exception -- either a 404 or a 500 would trigger it. Double check the logs of your rendering host for any errors.

Also, ensure you have the Experience Editor configured in your Startup.cs:

- A [`WithExperienceEditor` configuration](https://github.com/Sitecore/Helix.Examples/blob/v10.0.1.0/examples/helix-basic-aspnetcore/src/Project/BasicCompany/rendering/Startup.cs#L79-L87) in your `ConfigureServices`
- A [`UseExperienceEditor` call](https://github.com/Sitecore/Helix.Examples/blob/v10.0.1.0/examples/helix-basic-aspnetcore/src/Project/BasicCompany/rendering/Startup.cs#L122) in your `Configure`

Additionally, if you are using/following the public Sitecore examples, you will need to ensure that the `EnableExperienceEditor` value of the `Sitecore` section in your `appsettings.json` is `true`, or that an environment variable (`Sitecore__EnableExperienceEditor`) is configured to `true`. This is used in the examples to allow disabling of the Experience Editor endpoint outside your firewall.

Answer (score 0):

based on chat on Slack channel , adding "EnableExperienceEditor": true solve the issue

also more detailed can be found https://robearlam.com/blog/net-core-renderinghost-experience-editor-404-error

Answer (score 0):

Such errors can also be triggered by 403 responses, either during run time or build time. It may be triggered by firewalls or network settings such as IP restrictions in any area of your stack, including your middleware.

Read these types of errors as, *"your back end and front end are not able to, or were not able to, communicate at some point"*.

You may also see this error in some cases:

```
[JSS] Error occurred during POST to remote rendering host: `https://www.company.com/api/editing/render`
```

If you are having a hard time locating the issue, check all of your logs, including build logs and networking logs. Look for individual requests with 4xx or 5xx responses.

Perhaps the most sinister manifestation of this is when your head builds without issue, but then afterwards, another build of the head is triggered (perhaps by a webhook or custom `publish:end` event handler) which supposedly completes successfully, but is actually stuck in a bad state due to the build process not being able to communicate with the back end during the build. The smoking gun will be any peculiar network requests/responses during your head build.

As a last note, you may not always be dealing with 4xx or 5xx responses. Depending on how your network / middleware is configured,  responses could also return 3xx codes, or no code at all (timeouts,  connection resets, or partial responses).